# PHP file recursive change array key on find

Tags: grep, php, recursive

I used PHP array

> `$lang['module']['1'] = 'Title';`
>   `$lang['module']['2'] = 'Title2';`
>   `$lang['value'] = 'text123';`

how i can use replace in terminal Key Value to CASE UPPER ?

> `$lang['VALUE']`
>   `$lang['MODULE']['1']`
>   `$lang['MODULE']['2']`
>   etc `..` recursion

`find /var/www/site.net/blog/ -iname '*.php' | xargs grep -E '\$lang\[' -sl`

finded only $lang[ ...

Please help me.

Comment: Should 1 and 2 also be changed? Eg., can text appear there?

Answer (score 2):

```
find /var/www/site.net/blog/ -iname '*.php' -exec grep -l "\$lang\['" {} \; \
-exec sed -i.bak "s/$lang\['\([^']*\)']/$lang['\U\1']/" {} \;
```

`-i` option is used with `.bak` to make backup file with `.bak` extension on the each file `sed` will change. It is useful in case there is type in `sed` and you will not loose all your data. In case you're sure everything is ok, you can use just `-i`. In this case it won't make a backup.

Comment: Let's hope he has GNU sed for the \U.

Comment: `find /var/www/site.net/blog/ -iname '*.php' -exec sed -E "s/$lang\['\([^']*\)']/$lang['\U\1']/" {} \;` is not work

Comment: my php array dinamic `$lang['VALUE']` `$lang['l1']['l2']['l3']` etc..

Comment: What's wrong? Are there any errors? Can you show them?